# Why is the collector swing greater than the power-supply voltage?

Tags: bjt

My Vcc = 12v and the voltage peak across the collector current is 1.46kV. why?[image: this is the given circuit for the lab]

Comment: What are the transformer inductances/parameters? What purpose was the CCS placed there for?

Comment: When you have a current source in circuit, references to voltage are irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

You have inductance, and when you turn off the transistor, the inductor magnetic field must discharge and it will generate voltage of v=L*di/dt.

You also have a 10mA constant current source, and it will provide any voltage necessary to keep 10mA flowing. 10mA through 500 kohm resistor is already 5000 volts.

Answer (score 3):

> *My Vcc = 12v and the voltage peak across the collector current is
> 1.46kV. why?*

Because you are open-circuiting a transformer winding. A transformer behaves like an inductor when the primary winding is open circuited and, the leakage inductance tries to maintain the current flow until the stored magnetic energy is zero. In trying to maintain the current flow, the leakage inductance will produce a massive back-emf and 1.4 kV sounds extremely feasible.

Comment: Most likely the CCS is doing all the work. Impossible to tell without a transformer inductance though.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve built an automotive ignition coil circuit. I’d say the simulation is in line with real-world behavior. Just make sure you get a proper high voltage rated transformer if you try it in real life.